# Customize CSS styling in a Jekyll template

Tags: html, css, jekyll, styling, jekyll-theme

I'm using Jekyll for the first time to build a portfolio site. I had no trouble with customizing the HTML but when I follow instructions on customizing the CSS, the changes I make are not applied after I do `bundle exec jekyll serve`. Here's what I've tried following instructions from this [github help link](https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/):
I created a CSS file (assets/css/style.css) and at the top of it I put this block of code:

```
--- 
---
@import "{{ site.theme }};

/* sample code to test it */

.button {
background-color: red;
}
```

Then, in the head.html file, I made sure to link this newly created stylesheet by adding this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{- 'assets/css/style.css' | relative_url -}}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{- 'assets/css/main.css' | relative_url -}}" />
```

Note that the main.css is the original CSS file  that comes with the template.
Afterward, when I refresh the page, the button has not changed. I'd appreciate any tips on what I should be doing differently. Thanks

Comment: You're loading `main.css` after you load `style.css`. Could it be overriding your custom styles in `style.css`? If you look in the network tab in your devtools, to you see your custom CSS getting loaded, or is it 404ing?

Answer (score 1):

Its has something to do with the order in which you are calling the css.

css has a cascade model, in which the last css you call has preference.

Try to put YOUR css after the one that comes by default.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{- 'assets/css/main.css' | relative_url -}}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{- 'assets/css/style.css' | relative_url -}}" />
```

If it does´t work, put an Important.

```
--- 
---
@import "{{ site.theme }};

/* sample code to test it */

.button {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

If that does´t work either, simple put another class to the button in the css AND the html

```
--- 
---
@import "{{ site.theme }};

/* sample code to test it */

.btn {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would try is to close the string.

Wrong:
`@import "{{ site.theme }};`

Right:
`@import "{{ site.theme }}";`

Comment: Please use code highlighting while sharing code snippets.